# Best practice to initialize IoC contained instance

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

If I use a IoC container and the strong implementation is instantiated at runtime, dunamically, which among the below initialization is a best practice?

```
var obj=FooIocContainer.Resolve<IInterface>();
```

or

```
IInterface obj=FooIoCContainer.Resolve<IInterface>();
```

Which one is better and why? Just being curious :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the scope of the object you create. If its local then var will do. If you need to expose it using public properties, use specific Interface types.